# Windows UWP header row above ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I am looking for solution to create row above ScrollViewer that will stick on top of page. Any solutions?

It should look like in "Movier" app:
[image]

Comment: Can you include more details or a sample image? What do you mean by "row above ScrollViewer"?

Comment: https://puu.sh/xf1GO/3d8367c994.png like in "Movier" app

Comment: Attach this image in your question

Comment: The answer is very simple they have used  `CommandBar`. I will post this as answer with syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CommandBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.CommandBar).

Here is a sample image. Source: [CommandBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.CommandBar)

[image]

Here is a code sample

```
<CommandBar VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <CommandBar.Content>
        <TextBlock Text="LIBRARY" FontSize="36"/>
    </CommandBar.Content>
    <AppBarButton Icon="Favorite" Label="Favorite" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
    <AppBarButton Icon="Zoom" Label="Search" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
    <AppBarButton Icon="Setting" Label="Setting" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
</CommandBar>
```

You can learn more about it in [CommandBar Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.CommandBar).

Comment: Now i should add top padding to ScrollViewer?

Comment: @K.Kempski Do you want CommandBar to overlay ScrollViewer or just about it?

Comment: I want to overlay :)

Comment: @K.Kempski Then why do you want to give top padding to ScrollViewer?

Comment: https://puu.sh/xf3Kx/8d65844c0e.png https://puu.sh/xf3Mt/e74d4a62b5.png because it did't show.